# AbstractSet.removeAll() method not working properly

Tags: java, abstractset

The code shown below does output:

**[b]**

**[a, b]**

However I would expect it to print two identical lines in the output.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    static void test(String... abc) {
        Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        s.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
        s.removeAll(Arrays.asList(abc));
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("A");
        test("A", "C");
    }
}
```

The spec clearly states that removeAll

> "Removes all this collection's elements that are also contained in the
>   specified collection."

So from my understanding current behavior is unpredictable . Please help me understand this

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use all uppercase or all lowercase, that is, when `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` is not in play? I suspect it only defines traversal order, but not the identity semantics, and `"X"` is still different from `"x"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an inconsistency in the implementation of `TreeSet<E>`, bordering on the bug. The code will ignore custom comparator when the number of items in the collection that you pass to `removeAll` is greater than or equal to the number of items in the set.

The inconsistency is caused by a small optimization: if you look at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractSet.java#AbstractSet.removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) of `removeAll`, which is inherited from `AbstractSet`, the optimization goes as follows:

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified = false;

    if (size() > c.size()) {
        for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
            modified |= remove(i.next());
    } else {
        for (Iterator<?> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            if (c.contains(i.next())) {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

you can see that the behavior is different when `c` has fewer items than this set (top branch) vs. when it has as many or more items (bottom branch).

Top branch uses the comparator associated with this set, while the bottom branch uses `equals` for comparison `c.contains(i.next())` - all in the same method!

You can demonstrate this behavior by adding a few extra elements to the original tree set:

```
s.addAll(Arrays.asList("x", "z", "a", "b"));
```

Now the output for both test cases becomes identical, because `remove(i.next())` utilizes the comparator of the set.

Comment: It's not a bug of `TreeSet`, it's clearly stated that if equals is not consistent with `compareTo` then `TreeSet` doesn't obey standard `Set` interface contract, which is what's happening here.

Comment: @Jack It would be one thing if it didn't obey it; however, it conditionally obeys it, depending on the size of the set relative to the size of the collection being removed from the set.

Comment: It's like undefined behavior in C++, they state that it fails the general contract of `Set`, which is not MUST work or MUSTN'T works. You simply shouldn't rely on the contract if you don't have a consistent implementation, what exactly happens and under what circumstance is irrelevant as you've been warned that you can't make any assumptions.

Comment: @Jack Introducing something that is similar to having undefined behavior into the standard library of a language that prides itself on the absence of undefined behavior (this whole "write once - run anywhere" thing) is simply wrong. At the very least, a method has to be consistent with its own behavior. It is easier to make this code consistent by overriding `removeAll` than to explain why it should remain the way it is. After all, competing frameworks with nearly identical collections library don't have this behavior (.NET's `ISet<T>`/`SortedSet<T>` pair).

Comment: I'm not saying that this is good or bad. I'm saying that this is not a bug but something that the developer should be aware of since it's clearly specified.

Comment: It must be LOL (Level of limitation) if not a bug. I am not sure about this :(

Answer (score 6):

You only read documentation partly. You forgot one important paragraph from `TreeSet`:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; **it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface**.

Now `removeAll` implementation comes from `AbstractSet` and utilizes `equals` method. According to your code you will have that `"a".equals("A")` is not `true` so that elements are not considered equal even if you provided a comparator which manages them when used in the `TreeSet` itself. If you try with a wrapper then the problem goes away:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Test
{
    static class StringWrapper implements Comparable<StringWrapper>
    {
      public final String string;

      public StringWrapper(String string)
      {
        this.string = string;
      }

      @Override public boolean equals(Object o)
      { 
        return o instanceof StringWrapper && 
            ((StringWrapper)o).string.compareToIgnoreCase(string) == 0; 
      }

      @Override public int compareTo(StringWrapper other) { 
        return string.compareToIgnoreCase(other.string); 
      }

      @Override public String toString() { return string; }
    }

    static void test(StringWrapper... abc) 
    {
        Set<StringWrapper> s = new TreeSet<>();
        s.addAll(Arrays.asList(new StringWrapper("a"), new StringWrapper("b")));
        s.removeAll(Arrays.asList(abc));
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test(new StringWrapper("A"));
        test(new StringWrapper("A"), new StringWrapper("C"));
    }
}
```

This because you are now providing a consistent implementation between `equals` and `compareTo` of your object so you never have incoherent behavior between how the objects are added inside the sorted set and how all the abstract behavior of the set uses them.

This is true in general, a sort of rule of three for Java code: if you implement `compareTo` or `equals` or `hashCode` you should always implement all of them to avoid problems with standard collections (even if hashCode is less crucial unless you are using these objects in any hashed collection). This is specified many times around java documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the comparator `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` you use is not consistent with equals.

As stated by `TreeSet`:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided)
>   must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface.

Consistency with equals as stated by `Comparable`:

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if
>   e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2)
>   for every e1 and e2 of class C.

And as an example for the case insensitive comparator you use:

```
"a".compareTo("A") == 0 => true
```

while

```
"a".equals("A") => false
```